# ExtJS data model unknown amount of fields

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I have a data model that attempts to map all the incoming data, however I have to leave the data generic so i can add any number of meta data tags to my project.  How can I either map these data fields to the Model or access these items in the array when applying grid filters.

```
{
      "Link": "link.com",
      "Title": "project",
      "Description": "descript",
      "State": "TN",
      "Metadata": [
         {
            "Name": "County",
            "Value": "32"
         },
         {
            "Name": "Info",
            "Value": "info"
         },
         {
            "Name": "State",
            "Value": "TN"
         }
      ],
      "XMin": "-1",
      "XMax": "-1",
      "YMin": "1",
      "YMax": "1"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany

There is also nice explanation about filtering on that page

Comment: That works for filtering on a store, but how can I add filtering on the association to a grid filter?  Is there a way to write a custom filter function for the grid.  I can't seem to find one.  @Željko Mitrović

Comment: You would need to create custom grid filter by extending Ext.ux.grid.filter.Filter and then add that custom filter to a grid